# Orientation problem while using GKLeaderboardViewController

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit, game-center

Unfortunately, I don't understand UIViewControllers very well, nor do I understand exactly how they mesh with cocos2d scenes.  However, I am able to load a standard Game Center leaderboard view on top of my cocos2d (landscape-only) game successfully on the iPhone.  But, my game is a universal app and when I try it on iPad, the Game Center view loads in portrait orientation, is about half the size it should be (fills up only one quarter of the screen), and is not centered.  When I rotate the device, the Game Center view orients itself to landscape but gets really stretched out and looks like it wasn't designed for iPad in landscape view.

Does anyone have any advice?

```
- (void) showLeaderboard
{
    if(![MyAppDelegate isGameCenterAPIAvailable])   
        return;

    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated == YES)
    {
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        tempVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
        GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboard = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        if (leaderboard != NULL)
        {
            leaderboard.leaderboardDelegate = self;
            [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];

            // Pause game
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

            [tempVC presentModalViewController:leaderboard animated: NO];
            leaderboard.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0.0f));
            [leaderboard.view setCenter:CGPointMake(screenSize.height/2, screenSize.width/2)];
            leaderboard.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        }
    }
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    [tempVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [tempVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
    [tempVC release];
    tempVC = nil;

    // Resume game
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [Implementing iAds in Cocos2d Application](http://iosdevblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/implementing-iads-in-cocos2d-application/).

```
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
```

In this tutorial, addSubview UIView object to RootViewController.view, that is in the cocos2d application template, instead of EAGLView.

Comment: This answer was helpful; however, it turns out that there is no standard Game Center leaderboard view for iPad as of iOS 4.3.x